# How to get a list of source path/destination path pairs from a wix project

Tags: wix

I would like to create a script that will update files in the (default) install location with files from the source location where needed, based on the .wxs files that I have. I need to get this info from the wxs files, because the installation dir structure differs from the source location dir structure.

This would speed up my development cycle by not requiring a complete MSI uninstall/install when I have only recompiled one DLL for instance.

Is there functionality available in the Wix toolset that can give me a list of corresponding source and destination paths or would I have to implement everything including parsing of the Wix XML files myself?

I did not see anything relevant in the [List of Tools](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/alltools.html) section of the Wix documentation.

Answer (score 0):

***Alternative Approach***: I would suggest using the commercial file and directory syncing and comparison tool [**Beyond Compare**](https://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=gallery) to copy files to the destination directory with ease if this is just for QA. I guess you can use post build steps too, but Beyond Compare is very nice and reliable. It has the features you need for just about anything related to comparison of files and folders (**not affiliated**). You can let the application just sit there and you can do a full comparison on the fly whenever needed. Essential software for deployment people. [**Alternatives exist of course (list)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools).

Comment: In my case I don't think this will work because the directory structure in the installation folder differs from the directory structure containing the build results. The wxs files is where this mapping is made. I have updated my question to make this more clear. Do you agree?